# Python script doesn't start

Tags: python, linux, serial-port, timeout

I'm just starting with Python and Linux.

I made a program with Python that comunicates with a serial LCD over the ttyS0, and made a script to start it at boot. I disable the line '#T0:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyS0 115200 vt100' in inittab to prevent problems. What I get are diferent behaviours depending how I start the program.

1. When I ran the program in console mode 'python /home/python/glv.py' everything works fine.
2. When I ran the script in console mode that will start the program (/etc/init.d/glv.py) everything works fine.
3. When I reboot the board the script starts in default runlevel 3 but I have consecutives timeouts comunicating with the LCD. Sometimes the LCD show some output but usually for all the commands sent to the LCD I get a timeout. I can see that in the Log.

I can't use another ttyS* because there are other equipments using them. The other equipments are working Ok.
I first try to use the inittab like this 'null::respawn:python /home/python/glv.py' but the behaviour is the same.

**Example of the Log:**

```
2014-10-06 13:48:30,407 - __main__ - DEBUG - ***************** 
2014-10-06 13:48:30,420 - __main__ - DEBUG - *** Start GLV *** 
2014-10-06 13:48:30,432 - __main__ - DEBUG - *****************
2014-10-06 13:48:30,444 - lcd - INFO - Initialize 
2014-10-06 13:48:35,492 - lcd - ERROR - Didn't receive an answer in ClearScreen 
2014-10-06 13:48:38,588 - lcd - ERROR - Didn't receive an answer in SetLandscape 
2014-10-06 13:48:41,635 - lcd - ERROR - Didn't receive an answer in SetBackgroundColor 
2014-10-06 13:48:44,681 - lcd - ERROR - Didn't receive an answer in SetForegroundColor 
2014-10-06 13:48:47,728 - lcd - ERROR - Didn't receive an answer in SetTextBackgroundColor 
2014-10-06 13:48:50,791 - lcd - ERROR - Didn't receive an answer in EnableTouchScreen 
2014-10-06 13:48:53,837 - lcd - ERROR - Didn't receive an answer in ClearScreen 
2014-10-06 13:48:56,884 - lcd - ERROR - Didn't receive an answer in ClearScreen 
2014-10-06 13:48:59,931 - lcd - ERROR - Didn't receive an answer in SetForegroundColorGreen 
2014-10-06 13:49:02,978 - lcd - ERROR - Didn't receive an answer in SetTextBackgroundColor1 
2014-10-06 13:49:06,024 - lcd - ERROR - Didn't receive an answer in preparing WriteTextPos
```

**The Environment:**

```
The Linux distro: PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
The Python version: Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 23 2014, 01:44:56) 
The Hardware: Terra Board from ACME with AriaG25 
The command line in the script is just 'python /home/python/glv.py'
```

So, anyone knows why I get timeouts in the LCD only when the program is started by the script after a reboot?
I can't figure it out by myself.

**EDIT:**

As an example to set the BackgroundColor of the LCD:

```
def SetBackgroundColor(self):
    toSend = "\xFF\xA4\x19\xEB"
    state, res = self.SendBytesAndWaitResponse(toSend, "\x06", 3)
    if(state != 0):
        self.logger.error("Didn't receive an answer in SetBackgroundColor")

def SendBytesAndWaitResponse(self, toSend, toWait, timeout):
    strres = ""
    try:
        while(self.lockcomm):
            time.sleep(0.1)
        self.lockcomm = True
        start_time = time.time()
        end_time = start_time + timeout

        self.ser.write(toSend)
        while True:
            cur_time = time.time()
            if cur_time >= end_time:
                return (-1, strres)
            else:
                result = self.ser.read() 
                strres += result
                if(strres.find(toWait) != -1):
                    return (0, strres)
    except:
        return (-1, strres)
    finally:
        self.lockcomm = False
```

I send 4 bytes, the char to expect and set the timeout to 3 seconds (it's a lot) and never get the response that is implemented in the LCD (the char 0x06) in those 3 seconds.

Comment: Are you certain that data is being sent in this case (where you expect a response)? Do you have a logic analyzer to sniff the serial line? That you've created logging is a good first step, but the information in the log doesn't help you troubleshoot end to end, and since it's possible for logs to misrepresent things, it's good to have an alternate route for verification.

The way this is so intermittent has me thinking your end-device may be misbehaving.

Comment: I'm realy getting a timeout for almost every command sent to the LCD. It's not just the log file, I can see in the LCD that very few thing are write to it. But if I run it from a console it works fine. I don't have a serial sniffer for Linux. This is embedded linux in a small board, not a PC. Do you know any serial sniffer for this?

Comment: Salae makes decent probes for hobbyists. Saves so much debugging time. Are you able to show your code so that we can better understand the problem? It's not entirely clear what you mean by timeout (system call to write serial data? Or wait time for LCD response? Etc.)

Comment: What I'm getting at is that if you say you expect a response, you have to prove that you've sent a command (in the scenario where you see the error)